# Type comment list of values

Tags: python, python-2.x, jython, python-typing, pylance

I'm using Jython 2.1, so I cannot use type annotations (`{var}: {type}`) but I use type comments (`# type: {type}` for variables and `# type: ({param_type}) -> {ret_type}` for functions).

I would like to specify that a variable/parameter can only contain specific values, but I don't find any info online.

I tried:

- `variable = "first" # type: "first" | "second"`: Pylance raises `"first" is not defined` (same for `second`)
- `variable = "first" # type: "first|second"`: Pylance raises `"first" is not defined` (same for `second`)
- `variable = "first" # type: first | second`: Pylance raises `"first" is not defined` (same for `second`)
- `variable = "first" # type: Literal["first", "second"]`: Pylance raises `"Literal" is not defined` (same for `second`)

I thought of using a `try` block to make it work only in my environment like this:

```py
try:
    from typing import Literal
except:
    pass

variable = None # type: Literal["first", "second"]
```

This actually works (Pylance raises `Expression of type "None" cannot be assigned to declared type "Literal['first', 'second']"`), but also complicates the code that will be deployed in production, potentially leading to bugs caused by name clashing (e.g. what if someone creates a custom `typing` module which does a completely different thing?)

Is there any way to do it natively, *without* having to import anything?

Comment: I don't really understand your argument about name collisions. How is that different for _any_ other module? Or do you intend to just never use _any_ modules from the standard library? Besides, all you do is import something from the module to use in a type hint. If that hypothetical anti-`typing` module does some horrific stuff _on import_, I think you'll have bigger problems.

Comment: In any case, `typing.Literal` **is the way** to annotate specific literal values.

Comment: @DaniilFajnberg I know that it's the way, but i wanted to know if there is really no other alternative. I am using a hybrid development workstation (my local IDE uses 3.x and test-production have 2.1) so i try to write as close as possible to python 3.x (for example, using the parenthesis on the `print` statement) but i CANNOT use the `typing` module since it was added in `2.7` and the internal repository of the project packages is **huge** and maintained by **lots** of people, so name clashing is a probability i need to take care of.

Comment: And for name collision i mean that some colleague (which could even not be from my own country) could create a `typing` module which (for example) adds some useful modules in the production environment (remember, it uses *python 2.1*). This may destroy my script logic and cause it to fail even if it is a false positive

Comment: I see. I have to admit, it is _astounding_ and somewhat unsettling to me how people/companies can still rely on Python 2 these days (let alone **`2.1`**!). So you have my sympathy in that regard. I _would_ say an alternative to `Literal` can sometimes be an enum, but those are again Python 3 only and would therefore pose the same problem. I really don't see a practical solution for this. Other than... you know... not using Python 2. But I guess all the horrible security and stability implications of this are a much more pressing problem anyway, yet here we are...

Comment: @DaniilFajnberg I agree with you. Sadly, the IBM Websphere Application Server scripting engine uses Jython (and its latest version is 2.7.3) but in my current project (a bank) they are stuck at 2.1 (most probably due to legacy applications we must support). Being most of my Python knowledge based on Python >3.6 i had lots of difficulties triying to adapt to both the code style and the syntax (eg. no f-strings nor `string.format`, no `True`/`False`, no `json`/`Path`/`logging` modules, no `sorted` function, no `dict` type, etc... I could go on forever...). Thanks anyway